# _on_body_entered never triggers

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

To make interaction between my player and objects possible, I wanted to use composition and made an InteractionArea that I can then attach as the child to every object that should be interacted with. The area has a collision2d and the following (simplified) script:

```
extends Area2D
class_name InteractionArea


func _on_body_entered(body):
    print_debug('entered interaction area test 1')
    if body.is_in_group('player'):
        print_debug('entered interaction area test 2')
```

while the player is a CharacterBody2D and has a CollisionShape2D as child. The collision layer and mask of the InteractionArea are the same as the visibility layer of the player. However, the function _on_body_entered never triggers (none of the two messages is printed) and I just don't get why. I'm sure this is a big noob question and the solution is very simpple, but I just don't find it. I'd be very happy if someone could help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `collision_mask` of the `Area2D` should overlap with the `collision_layer` of what it will detect.

In general you want to use the `collision_layer` to specify what the body is, and the `collision_mask` to specify what it interact with.

---

> The collision layer and mask of the InteractionArea are the same as the visibility layer of the player

The visibility layer (in 2D) is for the `Viewport` (so you can have things show in one but not another, depending on the `canvas_cull_mask`). It is not what you want.

---

**Addendum**: Since apparently this is not the issue, the next thing to check would be if the `body_entered` signal is actually connected to the `_on_body_entered`.

If the signal is connected from the editor, when editing the script there should be a green icon on the left of `_on_body_entered` which indicates that it is connected.

It is also possible to make the connection from code using `connect`.

Refer to [Using Signals](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html) for details.

Comment: thank you! I checked and the collision_layer of my player is now on the same as the collision_mask of the area2D - However, still nothing happens...

Comment: @Inopinans What comes to mind is that the signal might not be connected, I have expanded the answer on that regard.